# Remove memsql node from webUI

Tags: singlestore, webui

Is there a way i can remove memsql node from the webUI itself ?

> I mean removing 3 or 4 different memsql nodes on different systems is tiresome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time MemSQL Ops only supports removing nodes from the command line.  To make this easier, you can iterate over the MemSQL id's you are interested in.  For example here is how I would delete all of the leaf nodes (escaped line break added for clarity):

```
memsql-ops memsql-list -q -r leaf \
| xargs -n 1 memsql-ops memsql-delete --delete-without-prompting
```

Or, if you just want to remove the nodes from the web-ui, but not delete the actual nodes you can use memsql-unmonitor in the same way as Joseph Victor mentioned.

```
memsql-ops memsql-list -q -r leaf \
| xargs -n 1 memsql-ops memsql-unmonitor
```

Hopefully we can get full management capabilities into the MemSQL Ops UI in an upcoming release.

Answer (score 0):

Try `memsql-ops memsql-unmonitor` on the terminal?